# Django Не отображаются модели на сайте

Tags: python, django

не выводится вообще никакая информация из модели на сайт.
Уже писал как угодно и что угодно, тупо ничего не отбражается.
3 день сижу, пересмотрел все видео и статьи на эту тему, документацию самого джанго,
не понимаю почему не отображается. Передаю все верно и вызываю тоже

тут уже нафигачил кучу разных выводов Product, но ни 1 парамент не отображается

```
{% load static tailwind_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.0.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.0.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    {% tailwind_css %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="bg-white border-b-2 border-indigo-800 px-4 lg:px-6 py-2.5">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto max-w-screen-xl">
                <a href="/home" class="flex items-center">
                    <img src="{% static 'main/img/logo.png' %}" width="250" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
                </a>
               
                <div class="hidden justify-between items-center w-full lg:flex lg:w-auto lg:order-1" id="mobile-menu-2">
                    <ul class="flex flex-col mt-2 font-semibold text-base lg:flex-row lg:space-x-8 lg:mt-0">
                            <a href="#" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-indigo-800 border-b border-black hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 lg:hover:text-primary-700 lg:p-0">Shop</a>
                                               
                            <a href="#" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-indigo-800 border-b border-black hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 lg:hover:text-primary-700 lg:p-0">Marketplace</a>
                       
                            <a href="#" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-indigo-800 border-b border-black hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 lg:hover:text-primary-700 lg:p-0">Features</a>
                       
                            <a href="#" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-indigo-800 border-b border-black hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 lg:hover:text-primary-700 lg:p-0">Team</a>
                        
                            <a href="#" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-indigo-800 border-b border-black hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 lg:hover:text-primary-700 lg:p-0">Contact</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center lg:order-2 ">
                    <a href="/users/login/" class="text-indigo-800 focus:ring-4 font-semibold rounded-lg text-lg px-4 lg:px-5 py-2 lg:py-2.5 mr-2 hover:bg-indigo-800 hover:text-white ">Log in</a>
                    <a href="/users/register/" class="text-indigo-800 focus:ring-4 font-semibold rounded-lg text-lg px-4 lg:px-5 py-2 lg:py-2.5 mr-2 hover:bg-indigo-800 hover:text-white ">Get started</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <h1 class="text-2xl m-10 font-bold">Login User</h1>
        <form class="w-2/5 bg-white-700 shadow-md m-10 rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ product }}
            <div class="mb-2">
                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Username</label>
                <p class="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 mr-10 text-gray-700 leading-tight">{{form.username}}</p>
                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mt-5 mb-2">Password</label>
                <p class="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 mr-10 text-gray-700 leading-tight">{{form.password}}</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{products.name}}</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl text-green-500 mb-2">$ {{products.price}}</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl text-indogo-500 mb-2">by: {{products.image}}</p>
                <h2>
                    <a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{products.category }}</a>
                </h2>
                <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">{{ products.description}}</p>  
                <p class="price">${{ product.price }}</p>
                {{ products.description|linebreaks }} 
                {% block content %}
<div id="sidebar">
<h3>Категория</h3>
<ul>
<li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
<a href="{% url 'flowers:product_list' %}">Все</a>
</li>
{% for c in categories %}
<li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
<a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="product-list">
<h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Товар{% endif %}</h1>
{% for product in products %}
<div class="item">
<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{%else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
</a>
<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
<br>
${{ product.price }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <button class="bg-indigo-800 text-white px-5 py-2" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="bg-sky-600 text-white px-5 py-2"><a href="{% url 'users:register' %}">Register?</a></button>
        </form>
        {{ product.name }}
    </div>
```

veiws.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product


def home(request):

    return render(request, 'home.html')

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'users/login.html',
                  {
                      'category': category,
                      'categories': categories,
                      'products': products
                  })


def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context = locals())
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorys'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Сама модель работает корректно, в админке все работает, добавление, удаление, редактирование.
Но при передаче в html и вызове Product там ничего не отображается на сайте.